# Differences in using Clausius-Duhem inequality vs Principle of Virtual Work/Power in derriving constitutive equations?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, thermodynamics, conservation-laws

I am a novice getting my toes wet in continuum mechanics and nonlinear elasticity. I have seen papers that use both approaches in developing constitutive connections to compliment balance equations of various sorts. My question is the energy inequality more general than the virtual work approach? I am tackling a visco-elastic problem where I will need to account for the time dependent relaxation of the material. Can this not be handled by virtual work since energy will be lost rather than conserved?

I ask because virtual work seems a bit more straight forward but I wonder if it is at the expense of applicability. I am looking for the pros and cons of both approaches.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Although I am not an expert in nonlinear elasticity, some general remarks on your question.

The principle of virtual work is a purely mechanical consideration, generalizing the concept of static equilibrium of forces to dynamics, i.e. the interaction forces of a body with its surroundings are considered in equilibrium with its inertial forces. It can be applied to conservative forces (where it leads to a Lagrangian) or to non-conservative forces (where it generally doesn't look so nicely, but can sometimes be deduced from Rayleigh's dissipation function in the Framework of Lagrangian mechanics). Nevertheless, even if the forces are non-conservative/dissipative, the principle of virtual work is ignorant to the heat that is produced in the process.

On the contrary, the Clausius-Duhem relation is the continuum-mechanical realization of the second law of thermodynamics. As such, it includes heat flow, entropy and the like. The only link to mechanics can be seen in the foundation of thermodynamics from statistical mechanics (how the motion of individual particles contributes to the macroscopic phenomena of heat, temperature, pressure and entropy/disorder).

It is possible that in some cases, both come to the same conclusions w.r.t. material laws, if heat production is kept out of the discussion. But none can completely substitute the other.

Just a stupid example: the principle of virtual work does not forbid viscous forces that increase energy instead of decreasing it (which, of course, would lead to instability, but does not impose a purely mechanical restriction). As opposed to this, the second law of thermodynamics explicitly prohibits the complete regeneration of mechanical energy from an equal amount of heat (which would constitute a perpetual motion machine of the second kind, which is forbidden by the second law of thermodynamics), and hence, also prohibits the mentioned "negative viscosity".